# Overwrote an image through, FTP, but it isn't showing up?

Tags: ftp

I just uploaded an overwrote an image with the exact same file name on to my site, but the old image is still showing up. Is there a delay sometimes in updating the images? Do I have to change the code if it is just an image with the same name?

Comment: Try hitting `Ctrl+F5` in your browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you haven't cached the image in your browser? Clear your cache and then try again or use another browser that you haven't visited that site with or hit F5 (or ctrl+f5) to force a refresh of that page/resource.

Comment: no.. unfortunately that wasn't it. Just gave it a try.

Comment: If that wasn't it, why the accepted answer?  If it was correct, please delete your comment.

Comment: Indeed, I am perplexed as well.

Answer (score 0):

FTP isn't prefect, try erasing or renaming the old file, then re-uploading it. I've found many ftp clients for me on mac os x simply do not overwrite succesfully even though they report that they have.

Answer (score 0):

Several things to consider, all of which I've run into:
1) Make sure to clear the cache
2) Make sure that you're copying to the correct folder. (this one drove a user nuts trying to figure out what what was happening.)
3) Make sure the file size has changed. If the file size is the same, delete the remote file and replace it.
and probably a few other things that I don't remember right now.